# Firebase Remote Config NullPointer

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm getting the following error:

```
09-04 10:45:50.429 4841-4869 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
    Process: com.xxx.xxx, PID: 4841
       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Set java.util.Map.keySet()' on a null object reference
           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalt.zza(Unknown Source)
           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalt.run(Unknown Source)
           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This error only gives me when I added Remote Config firebase code as they explain in the project code example.

This is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:23"
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.batriks.getblue"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':slidingMenu')
    compile project(':flip3DViewTransition')
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.2.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Top level gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I have added google-services.json also, and  proved several libs configs but nothing appears to work.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It seems like error in your `AsyncTask` class where you trying to get `Set` value from a `Map` object using `keySet` method using a null map object. Please cross check it first.

Comment: I have been working with the phone and it works, but it fails with the emulator :S

Comment: Use consistent versions of the Play Service and Firebase libraries.  Change Firebase versions to 9.4.0.  Also better NOT to use `play-services:9.4.0` and instead use the specific APIs you need.  Having `play-services` as a dependencies pulls in ALL the Play Services libs and all the Firebase libs.  See the section of [this doc](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) titled _Selectively compiling APIs into your executable_.

Comment: @MikelSanchez Can you paste your Java source code where it tries to fetch the configuration data from the remote? I believe this error is related to more on your source code rather than which version of Firebase Remote Config you depend on.

Comment: Thanks guys, this afternoon I will put my code and try to do @qbix suggestions

Comment: This could be another manifestation of the [bug](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/291), also reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42362024/firebase-remote-config-nullpointerexception-on-map-keyset).