# Firebase Remote Config AsyncTask Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, firebase, android-asynctask, crash-reports

I am getting the following crash for a lot of users:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Set java.util.Map.keySet()' on a null object reference

   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanw.zza(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanw.run(Unknown Source)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

A similar question is here: 
Visit [Firebase Remote Config NullPointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315234/firebase-remote-config-nullpointer)

But it doesn't have any answers.

Can anyone help how to resolve this issue?

**Edit:**

I found that the source crash points to is from Firebase-config library. In which keySet() method is called for a Map without checking for null. Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: Please provide code

Comment: Please share the code for the same

Comment: Why do you search a bug in the gradle file? The Log says that you've got an issue in an AsyncTask, it sould be in a java class. Post the code of that AsyncTask. If you didn't change the gradle file you shouldn't post it

Comment: your asyncktask   some value not storing because it is comming null

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for the comments. I am unable to find the source of the crash (as edited in the question). Please let me know how to know from where this crash may be coming?

Comment: and you r feching that null data

Comment: You didn't initialised the `HashMap` or `Map`

Comment: Hi @MikeKeepsOnShine, Thanks for the reply. I am unable to know which AsyncTask is being pointed to in the crash report. Can you help me find out?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not a real answer, but i post it anyway trying to make my thought more clear.

You can follow two way to find the bug

**FIRST (recommended)**

1. try to reproduce the crash.
2. If you can reproduce it, check the code of the relative
   section/module in which the app crashes. You should find an
   `AsyncTask` in which you use a `Map` or `HashMap` that you have to check if is null or not

**SECOND**

Check every `AsyncTask` in which you use a `Map` or `HashMap` and build a control to avoid `NullPointerException` on it

Comment: Thanks @MikeKeepsOnShine for the answer. Although, I have tried a lot but unable to reproduce the crash. And I have checked all AsyncTask and added a check for NullPointerException. But unable to resolve the issue. Though, I will try again to reproduce if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you are trying to call the method `keySet()` on a null map inside an `AsyncTask`. That should be pretty easy to isolate. How many places do you call keySet() in your AsyncTask?